# What is the best way to process multiple lines and extract a large list of specific strings?

Tags: bash, grep, find

I'm trying to process multiple lines and extract a specific list of IPs from the text file with a large list of IPs `(10000-ips.txt)`.

To extract specific IPs from the file, I would normally use:

```
egrep '111.11.111.11|222.22.222.22' 10000-ips.txt
```

But now I have to filter about 5000 IP and not only two `111.11.111.11|222.22.222.22` but  egrep return “Argument list too long”

Example:

```
egrep '5000-IPs-to-find' 10000-ips.txt
```

Return:

```
/usr/bin/egrep: Argument list too long
```

I like to know, what is the best way to do this?

Comment: [Q: Argument list too long - Unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6890632/argument-list-too-long-unix?r=SearchResults&s=1|183.9149) and more here [Error: “grep: Argument list too long” [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29727135/error-grep-argument-list-too-long) and in the duplicate linked there. `xargs` or `find` are two solutions.

Comment: Loop over IPs and invoke `grep`?

Comment: Hi @stephanmg Yes I was thinking about this, but will be slow.

Comment: @pancho: Did you benchmark it? Is the file very large?

Comment: If there are no actual regular expressions in those patterns, just put them in a file one per line and use `grep -Ff 5000ips.txt 10000-ips.txt`

Comment: @tripleee that did the trick.  Thanks!